# How to update table in SQL server with out changing timestamp field value

Tags: sql-server

I want to update a table and prevent it's `timestamp` column to be updated automatically, how can I overcome?

for example I have this table

```
Table1 (id int,Name varchar(50),version timestamp)
```

consider I want to update Name but I don't want the version column get updated Automatically,

I tried

```
Update Table1 set Name = 'NewName' , [version] = [version]
```

but it doesn't work and says

`Msg 272, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot update a timestamp column.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not. Timestamp is not a timestamp - it is a row version number pretty much (read the documentation here). The problem is that an update does change the version. No cheating allowed. It simply is not possible. If you want this ability, you should never have used a timestamp but a manually maintained integer field.

Answer (score -2):

in updating a table it must be specified the column you wanted to updated  to the table were it is located

second way to solved it is to, get the current value and set into update stage  so it will retain the value of your timestamp

Comment: for the second way it says: `Msg 272, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot update a timestamp column.`